# Automatically fill in the subject line of contact form

Tags: 8, emails

Is there a way to automatically fill in fields in Drupal 8 Contact forms, for example by passing the value in the URL? E.g.

/contact/myform?subject=Subject%20line

If Drupal doesn't have this built-in, does anyone know of a javascript plugin that will do this?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in way to do this with the contact entity form. The [prepopulate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) looks like it would be covered under this scenario, but it doesn't work on contact forms.

As an alternative, a simple form alter with a custom module could do this on the back end, or front end, with a [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) invocation.

The backend solution could alter the default form value:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Set the default subject based off the subject query param.
  $default_subject = \Drupal::request()->query->get('subject');
  $form['subject']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default_subject;
}
```

Or the frontend solution can attach a custom JS file:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Assuming mymodule has defined a drupal.mymodule library 
  // within mymodule.libraries.yml
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/drupal.mymodule';
}
```

Then have the attached JS attach to a Drupal behavior:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

  // Attach a drupal behavior that uses jQuery to alter the form value.
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function () {
      var subject = '';
      // @TODO: parse location.search for the subject query param.
      $('#edit-subject-0-value').val(subject);
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: Hi, on my side, the prepropulate module worked with the Contact form.